# How I can convert any JavaScript variable to Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript

I need to send the binary representation of a varibale trough websocket, the problem is the variable can be string, can be intiger, can be anything.

```
function send(bar) {
    var foo = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(bar); // Works if 'bar' is string
    var foo = new Int32Array([bar]).buffer; // Works if 'bar' is integer
}
```

**How I can convert any JavaScript variable to *Uint8Array* ?**

Objective:

`send('Hello')` **->** `0x48 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F`

`send(123)` **->** `0x7B`

*Note: I don't have control of the server side*

Comment: Convert it to string with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: No!, JSON.stringify is for JSON... I'm looking for Uint8Array.

Comment: I mean, get it into string, and you already know how to encode a string, right?

Comment: @Dimava that will not work, because many values might create improper UTF values.

Comment: How `JSON.stringify` will solve `send(88)` ?

Comment: What @Dimava is trying to say is that JSON.stringify returns a string for any kind of variable - int, str, obj, etc. So use the stringify function to make it into a string, and then convert it into a buffer the same way as you would with a string.

Comment: `new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(/* "88" */ JSON.stringify(88))`

Comment: There's no facility in the language that does what you want. You'll have to determine exactly how strings and numbers should be encoded for your server code, and then write your own client-side code to do that.

Comment: @Pointy, good one, probably the solution is to detect the datatype first of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy), I solve it by checking the datatype before conversion.

```
// 123 -> ["123"]
// "123" -> ["123"]
// True -> ["1"]
// False -> ["0"]
function convert_var_to_uint8array_string(bar) {
    if(typeof bar === 'string') { var foo = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(bar); } 
    else if(typeof bar === 'number') { var foo = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(bar); } 
    else if(typeof bar === 'boolean') { var tmp = 0; if(bar) tmp = 1; var foo = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(tmp); } 
    else { var foo = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode('undefined'); }
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WebSockets support sending string data,

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://...");

socket.send(JSON.stringify(123));
socket.send(JSON.stringify("wasd"));
socket.send(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
```

and then `JSON.parse` it on accepting side

```
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have control of the server side.

Comment: Then you can't send "anything" as the server doesn't now how to read it

Comment: The server developer is in my team, but he expects a `void*` in C#. He asked me to convert at least `string` and `integer` to `Uint8Array()`.

Comment: You mean to "UTF8String" and "uint8"(has values 0-255) ?

Comment: I guess you are a high level developer :) but, any kind of string is just a series of bytes 0-255, actually, the whole computer data science is just a series of 0-255 !